# Let's delete or lock the what-blogs-to-read question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, community-wiki

[What blogs should I be following if I am learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-blogs-should-i-be-following-if-i-am-learning-photography)

This question has a lot of votes, but is a poorly maintained community wiki. It has had one non-spam update in the past year. And most of the answers are one-line "Don't forget Site XYZ!"

Blogs are a fast-moving topic -- for this to work it would really need constant curation. As it is, it's just attracting spammers and self-promotion. When this question arrived on the site, I think there was an expectation that poll-type questions would be effective with the voting system. But experience has shown that not to be the case.

There are a few good links in there, but I can't see this question being more helpful to a newbie than a google search. (And probably less helpful.) Time to nuke it? Since it is community wiki, no one's reputation will be adversely affected.

Comment: I've put a historical significance lock, though it seems to expire. I've also protected it, which should minimize the spam.

Comment: Figured out the perma-lock, just need to be on a better device than an iPhone to spot it...